# Multiprocess wont execute simultaneously

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Ive checked this all sorts of ways, not sure why my various processes wont start and run at the same time there is no error to google as it does work for the most part

```
 from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event #for threading

 class WebScraper(object):
     def __init__(self, pq, e): 
         self.pdfQueue = pq
         self.e = e 

     def run(self):
         i = 0
         while True:
             print('tweet scraper online')
             i = i + 1    #testing
             if i == 10:  #testing
                 e.set()  #testing TODO remove

             if self.e.is_set():
                 print("killing tweet scraper")
                 break


 class DataParser(object):
      def __init__(self, pq, dq,  e):
          self.pdfQueue = pq
         self.dataQueue = dq
         self.e = e
         self.count = 0


      def run(self):

          while True:
              pdf = self.pdfQueue.get()
              print ('parsing pdf')
              self.e.set()
              if self.e.is_set():
                  print ('killing database parser')
                  break


 class DatabaseWriter(object):
     def __init__(self, dq, e): 
          self.dataQueue = dq
          self.e = e 

     def run(self):

         while True:
              print("database writer")
              if self.e.is_set():
                  print ('killing database writer')
                  break


 if __name__ == '__main__':

      print('\nStarting script')
      e = Event()
      pq = Queue()
      dq = Queue()
      ws = WebScraper(pq,  e)
      dp = DataParser(pq, dq, e)
      dw = DatabaseWriter(dq, e)

      p1 = Process(target=ws.run)
      p1.start()
      p2 = Process(target=dp.run)
      p2.start()
      p3 = Process(target=dw.run)
      p3.start()

      p1.join()
      p2.join()
      p3.join()
```

The output is as follows it runs quickly with nothing unexpected as you can see both processes

```
 Starting script
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 tweet scraper online
 killing tweet scraper
 database writer
 killing database writer
```

If I remove the if statement in WebScraper class WebScraper and DatabaseWriter start but DatabaseParser does not look to be running

Answer (score 1):

Your self.pdfQueue.get() is blocking the rest of the method in your DataParser instance. See [https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get](http://Your%20self.pdfQueue.get()%20is%20blocking%20the%20rest%20of%20the%20method%20in%20your%20DataParser%20instance.%20See%20https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get)